# datepicker not formatting to mm/dd/yy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker

Any suggestions on how I can format the date to be `mm/dd/yy`? This option does not work:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

The problem I have is after the date is saved and I go back to edit it, it is showing the date as 1901 since it is parsing 2016-01-01.  How do I store the date in the database as `mm/dd/yy`?  It seems like I need to add the formatting to  `<%= f.text_field :jobdate, "data-provide" => 'datepicker', class: "form-control" %>`

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_appointment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /appointments
  # GET /appointments.json
  def index
    @appointments = Appointment.all
  end

  # GET /appointments/1
  # GET /appointments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /appointments/new
  def new
    @appointment = Appointment.new
  end

  # GET /appointments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /appointments
  # POST /appointments.json
  def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @appointment.save

        format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @appointment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /appointments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /appointments/1.json
  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @appointment.update(appointment_params)

        format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :ok, location: @appointment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /appointments/1
  # DELETE /appointments/1.json
  def destroy
    @appointment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to appointments_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_appointment
      @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def appointment_params
      params.require(:appointment).permit(:First_Name, :last_name, :phone, :cellphone_yes, :cell_provider, :jobdate, :time_start, :time_stop, :status, :location, :service, :sales_person, :technician, :year, :make, :model, :vehicle_type, :cost, :glass_number, :glass_ordered, :portland, :pilkington, :glass_type, :glass_type_other, :how_paid, :paid_type, :insurance, :insurance_company, :vin, :referral, :heated_wiper, :rain_sensor, :condensation_sensor, :electrochromatic, :lane_departure, :molding_needed, :molding_number, :molding_ordered, :other_phone, :work_business_name, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :notes)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery datepicker will send the date back to your rails app as text; once you are happy with the way the date is displayed on screen, you can parse it correctly in your controller, using `strptime`. In your case, if you want `mm/dd/yy`, you can just change the parameters you receive, like so:

```
def appointment_params
  original_params = params.require(:appointment).permit(:First_Name, :last_name, :phone, :cellphone_yes, :cell_provider, :jobdate, :time_start, :time_stop, :status, :location, :service, :sales_person, :technician, :year, :make, :model, :vehicle_type, :cost, :glass_number, :glass_ordered, :portland, :pilkington, :glass_type, :glass_type_other, :how_paid, :paid_type, :insurance, :insurance_company, :vin, :referral, :heated_wiper, :rain_sensor, :condensation_sensor, :electrochromatic, :lane_departure, :molding_needed, :molding_number, :molding_ordered, :other_phone, :work_business_name, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :notes)
  original_params.merge({jobdate: Date.strptime(original_params.delete(:jobdate), '%m/%d/%y')})
end
```

You should also send the correctly formatted date to the form. To do this, the simplest is possibly to just set the field value rather than playing with the format:

```
<%= f.text_field :jobdate, "data-provide" => 'datepicker', :value => (@model_instance.jobdate || Date.today).strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>
```

You have to also be consistent with the format in your jQuery datepicker configuration:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
});
```

Comment: I am not sure where to put model_instance.jobdate = Date.strptime(params[:jobdate], '%m/%d/%y') in my controller.  I assume that until I do I will keep getting error Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/agss/app/views/appointments/_form.html.erb where line #98 raised:

undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass when I am using <%= f.text_field :jobdate, "data-provide" => 'datepicker', :value => @appointment.jobdate.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>

Comment: I wil be using @appointment.jobdate = Date.strptime(params[:jobdate], '%m/%d/%y')

Comment: If you add your controller action code I'll tell you exactly how to change it.

Comment: I am a newbie and it will not let me post the contents of  appointment_controller.rb.  It says too many characters to post here.  What are my options?

Comment: I added it to my original post but it seems to have done something weird to this post.  Let me know if I need to do it another way.

Comment: Two new problems occurred.  When I enter 01/01/2016 using datepicker and your code changes it is saving jobdate as 01/01/2020.  Also, when I go back to edit mode the date shows 01/01/20 is coming up with January 1, 1920 in datepicker.  How do I format for the full yyyy?

Comment: Also, after I hit submit after entering the date for jobdate, and it displays all my fields on the next screen jobdate shows as Job Date: 2020-01-01.  So when I am reading it back into the edit mode form it is takking the 3rd and 4th characters as the year to get the 20 for 1920 is what I am assuming is what is causing this.

Comment: You still need to take care of the datepicker formatting in your javascript, I assumed you already did this (added to my answer). Of course if rails is expecting the year with 2 digits and you send 4 it won't work… The tag for the year with 4 digits is `%Y` with capital Y.

Comment: Where does the capital %Y go?  None of the code examples you suggested used a capital Y.  Here is my current code: <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="jobdate">Job Date:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-7">
            <%= f.text_field :jobdate, "data-provide" => 'datepicker', :value => @appointment.jobdate.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>
           <script>       
             $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
             dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
             });
           </script>
        </div>

Comment: Now for some reason while running this code this morning I am getting error message: Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/agss/app/views/appointments/_form.html.erb where line #98 raised:

undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass.   This worked last night and I can not figure out why I am now getting this error message.

Comment: Looking into strftime nil problem and others have had this problem. Looks like when the jobdate is blank it is not liking the strftime.  Trying some of the solutions I am seeing is not working to fix the problem.

Comment: I was able to get things working.  Thanks for  your help.

Comment: I just found out it works when I am using edit mode but I am still getting this error when I am in create (new) mode.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I have changed my answer, there was indeed a problem on create.

Comment: Thank you very much for the outstanding help.  I really appreciate it. You would think date and telephone stuff would be much easier with Rails but I am not find that is the case. If you could please check out my other question regarding maskedinput for a telephone number, titled "Telephone mask not working with maskedinput" I would really appreciat e it.

Comment: I'll have a look. Could you accept my answer if it is satisfactory?

Comment: I just accepted.  Sorry I had forgot to do it earlier.